# TestNG annotations are not respected when run group based tests through command line

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I want to run my tests based on their groups through command line with Maven.(means if I say `mvn test -Dgroups=sanity`, only tests marked with `sanity` group will be run)

For achieving above, I've following code in pom.xml. Because of following if nothing is provided on command line for group i.e `mvn test`, it will run tests with `regression` group

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.maven.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <groups>regression</groups>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.47.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <groups>${groups}</groups>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

and my test class has `BeforeClass` and `AfterClass` annotations:

```
public class SanityTest {
  @Test(groups={"sanity"})
  public void f() {
    System.out.println("This is sanity test");
  }

  @BeforeClass
  public void beforeClass() {
    System.out.println("This is before class.");
  }

  @AfterClass
  public void afterClass() {
    System.out.println("This is after class.");
  }
}
```

In order to run sanity tests, I hit `mvn test -Dgroups=sanity`. Sanity tests does run but `AfterClass`, `BeforeClass` methods are not executed.

Its output is:

```
This is sanity test
```

actually, here I'm expecting:

```
This is before class.
This is sanity test
This is after class.
```

Could someone please help me what needs to be done so that TestNG annotations are also respected?

Comment: Show full pom file and please add a full output of `mvn clean test` ..

Comment: khmarbaise, I updated question with complete pom.xml. Should I add output of `mvn clean test` or `mvn clean test -Dgroups=sanity`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the alwaysRun attribute to your @BeforeClass and @AfterClass annotiations:

From the testNG docs:
**alwaysRun**   For before methods (beforeSuite, beforeTest, beforeTestClass and beforeTestMethod, but not beforeGroups): If set to true, this configuration method will be run regardless of what groups it belongs to. 
For after methods (afterSuite, afterClass, ...): If set to true, this configuration method will be run even if one or more methods invoked previously failed or was skipped.